# ¿Cómo alterar una table de varias base de datos?

Tags: sql, sql-server, update

Tengo 45 bases de datos que tienen en común una tabla llamada 'site'. Necesito alterar la misma tabla en todas las bases de datos.

Este es mi update statement:

```
update site set url = 'http://test.internal.org/' where SiteKey = 'ABC123'
```

Como puedo hacer esto en SQL server 2012?

Comment: estan en la misma instancia?

Comment: Investiga sobre sql dinámico

Comment: Si esta sobre la misma instancia (servidor)

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que esta es un requerimiento de mantenimiento de las bases y que no es un requisito frecuente. Lo que puedes es construir una consulta para generar las sentencias de actualización. Primero necesitamos la lista de bases de datos:

```
SELECT name 
       FROM master.sys.databases
```

Ahora, la completamos con la sentencia de actualización:

```
SELECT 'update ' + name + '..site set url = ''http://test.internal.org/'' where SiteKey = ''ABC123''' 
       FROM master.sys.databases
       where name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb');
```

La salda serán las sentencias de actualización en cada base, resta copiar, verificar  y eliminar eventualmente alguna que no corresponda.